# How to prevent the server from stacking due to continuous requests

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a web application i have developed for processing payments. How it works is that, the user of the system requests a paid service and the system generates the invoice for payment which is valid for 7 days.The user goes to bank or uses mobile to make payment.

If the user does not make payment within 7 days, i want to automatically flag these invoice as 'EXPIRED' and thus the user has to request for new invoice.

I have implemented an ajax call for every 10 seconds to check for any invoices which have expired and flag them as 'EXPIRED'

It is doing fine but i have a challenge that at some point the server gets stacks and i think it is due to these requests which are being sent for every 10 sec.

I am using PHP-POSTGRESQL and i have implemented my codes in php.

Is there any way i can avoid or prevent my server from stacking???

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like this may be a job for `cron jobs`. Also, running every 10 seconds makes for a *very* fast poll, which you may want to consider slowing down.

Comment: why are you posting evey 10 seconds?  Why not run a cron job in the background to do expired invoices?

Comment: Seems like you're going to a lot of unnecessary effort to know exactly when something times out, when it's already been sitting for a week.  Is marking it expired really that time-critical?  What action are you taking that is so important that it can't wait 11 seconds longer than the 604800 seconds waited to get to this point? I'm just pointing out that you might be caught up in doing something simply because you can; not because you need to.